# loop in a step in spring batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a migrations of data to do, I think I could use spring batch.
I have around 1 millions of customer in a table (paging).
For each of them I need to get data from two table.
On the result of theses two tables I need to do some operation.
Finaly I need to write the result to database.

My concern is about how to start the both reading and linking data from the loop of the customer...

default pattern of spring batch

- read
- process
- write

what I need to do

- read customer and for each of them

  - read table x
  - read table y
  - process (get result of both read)
  - write in table z

Is there any possiblity with spring batch?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are 3 options to handle your requirements:

#### 1) One big query for all tables

If this is possible, it might be the simpler option from a Spring Batch point of view, because you would only have 1 reader + 1 processor + 1 writer.

But maybe it isn't possible is your case (when dealing with different databases, for instance).

#### 2) Writing a custom reader

It might be tricky, but one possibility would be for you to write your own reader implementation, which would fetch data from all the tables you need.

The tricky part would be dealing with pagination in all those tables at the same time.

#### 3) Chaining processor to fetch more data

Finally, you could read only the customer data in the reader, and then have processors fetch additional data for each of those customers from other tables. It's possibles by using Spring Batch's [CompositeItemProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemProcessor.html).

In this case your step would consist of:

- customer table reader
- composite processor

  - table X processor
  - table Y processor
  - process all results
- write to target database

Answer (score 1):

> For each of them I need to get data from two table

You can use the [driving query pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders). The idea is to enrich items in an item processor. In your case, this consists in doing the additional query to get the details of the current customer.

This pattern performs well for small/medium datasets, but might be a bit slow for large datasets due to the additional query. But at least it works well for all cases and I think it is suitable for what you are asking for.

Otherwise, you would need to create a single query joining the 3 tables and use the regular chunk-oriented processing of Spring Batch.